# Trying to set up a paginated query on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set up a paginated query on my firebase database.

I have data in this format

```
"posts":
{
    1 : {//more nested data}
    2 : {}
    3 : {}
}
```

And so on.

I'm trying to set up a query on Android such that it fetches 5 nodes at a time.

I tried this 
Note : mDBref points to /posts

```
mDBRef.orderByKey()
.startAt("1")
.limitToFirst(5)
.ref();
```

And running a single value event listener on that ref.

However I'm getting in my dataSnapshot all the 7 elements I have within /posts

Apologies in advance for the formatting, I'm posting this on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last `ref()` call at the end returns the reference to the entire location.

Do this instead:

```
Query query = mDBRef.orderByKey()    
    .startAt("1")
    .limitToFirst(5);
```

Two additional points:

- The method is called `getRef()` on Android, not `ref()`.
- Where did you get the idea from to add `ref()` at the end? I've seen this mistake a few times recently and would like to remove the source of it if possible.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I spent a whole lot of time debugging this. 

And yes, my mistake, I typed .ref() by mistake as I was typing from memory.


I believe I had seen the .ref() statement in legacy docs for firebase(pre-Google ones). Might have been for a JS context, just tried hacking at it on Android.

Comment: OK, thanks for confirming that this was the problem. Where did you get the idea from to add that call to `ref()`/`getRef()` at the end of the query? I'm really trying to understand, to see if we can optimize something for future developers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to find the exact post/tutorial via which I got the idea from. Sorry I couldn't help you out, but I'll try digging it up from my history and comment here if I find it.